# SDL2 Joystick Axis

Tags: c, sdl-2, ubuntu-15.10

I'm just getting my gamepad setup for SDL2, I've been creating a mapping for the `SDL_GameControllerAddMapping` function. Everything has worked except for the movement and look axes on my pad.

Setup like this:

```
game_state->joystick = SDL_JoystickOpen( 0 );
```

Then listen to the events like this:

```
SDL_Joystick* js = game_state->joystick;

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < SDL_JoystickNumAxes( js ); ++i )
{
  int axis = SDL_JoystickGetAxis( js, i );
  printf( "a%d: %d\n", i, axis );
}
```

Close like this:

```
SDL_JoystickClose( game_state->joystick );
```

At the moment `game_state` is just a struct with nothing but an `SDL_Joystick*` in it.

I get output similar to this:

```
a0: 0
a1: 0
a2: -32768
a3: 0
a4: 0
a5: -32768
```

If I pull the triggers all the way down I get:

```
a0: 0
a1: 0
a2: 32767
a3: 0
a4: 0
a5: 32767
```

This tells me that the triggers should be mapped to a2 and a5, but the movement and look axes don't change these values and they don't show up for any of the other joystick input types. I've already used `SDL_JoystickGetHat`, `SDL_JoystickGetButton` and `SDL_JoystickGetBall` to map the rest of the pad.

None of the other buttons change these values either. I'm not sure, but I'm probably missing something. I've looked through the SDL2 wiki, but I didn't find anything that helped. I've also googled around for mappings for my pad, but the only thing I could find was [this](https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB). Unfortunately they are missing mine. Other Google results suggest using Steam's Big Picture Mode to configure my pad, as that will generate an SDL2 mapping, but my brain wouldn't engage and I didn't understand what I was supposed to do.

I'm using these [drivers](https://github.com/paroj/xpad). Before installing them my pad wasn't recognised at all. After installing I get this problem.

---

## Update:

I've had a play with jstest-gtk and it reports the same thing. It says six axes are present, but 0, 1, 3, 4 don't seem to be triggered by anything on the pad.

---

## Edit:

Oh I forgot to mention that I'm using ubuntu 15.10.

---

## Update 2:

I now have an official xbox one pad and it's working fine. The problem with the other pad still exists though. It's a Rock Candy Wired Controller for Xbox One.

I've also use both the pads on Steam. The problem with the Rock Candy is present there too. For now I'm going to assume it's a problem with the drivers. The source is available, but I have no experience with the Linux kernel, so for the sake of my system I'm going to leave it alone.